# How to set up models-table-server-paginated for use

Tags: ember.js

How to set up models-table-server-paginated for use.

in template file

```
{{models-table-server-paginated
  data=rolesList
  columns=tableColumns
  useNumericPagination=true        
}}
```

in js file

```
rolesList:Ember.computed(function(){
  var store = this.get("store");          
  return  store.query("role", { page: 1 });
}),
```

but not worked.

Comment: Is `models-table-server-paginated` an registered ember addon in http://emberaddons.com ?

Comment: I found in [emberobserver.com](https://emberobserver.com/addons/ember-models-table), its sample is by models-table.js and Works, but i can not set up models-table-server-paginated .

Comment: I couldn't find the addon

Comment: Thank you for your follow-up

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani I know this is old but I think OP is referring to https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-models-table

Comment: Thank you for your follow-up, I found it.